# mime.lookup is not a function in expressjs run inside docker

Tags: node.js, express, docker

I have a docker image running a node process. It is listening to a particular port. When i am trying to access the port using curl or through browser request, I am getting following error -

TypeError: mime.lookup is not a function
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:592:12)
    at ServerResponse.send (/E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:145:14)
    at app.get (/E:/Saurabh/apis/index.js:26:6)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/E:/Saurabh/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)

If i run same code without docker, then it works as expected.
What can be the issue?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: btw. i ran into this using express. i tried upgrading "mime" to 2.0.0, got the error, then downgraded back to 1.x and the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

As for [`npm` documentation on `mime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime):

> Version 2 is a breaking change from 1.x as the semver implies. Specifically:
>
> - lookup() renamed to getType()
>
> If you prefer the legacy version of this module please npm install mime@^1.

Just change the way you call the method to `mime.getType(path)` or uninstall mime `npm uninstall mime` and reinstall it as `npm install mime@^1`.